# Android Studio Gradle Build

Tags: build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

As you can see, my Gradle build took 4 min 15 sec. Every time I run my Android application it takes several minutes. What can I do to speed up Gradle Build?

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment two strings in your "gradle.properties" file

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

If you have no these strings you must add their to your file.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using **compileFiles** option to include your dependencies. using compileFiles to include your dependencies makes the included jars as part of your apk. and apk size increases and build takes time as apks of all flavour dimension are generated.

What you can do is to **provide** option to resolve dependencies of your apk. By using this your apk will make use of jars at compile time only and will not include it in final apk. Hence it will take less time to generate the apk.